# data decoding issue in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am unable to get response from this code

```
 if (!empty($data)) {

      $json_response = json_encode($data);

      echo $json_response;exit;
  } else {
      echo '';
  }
```

here data is a coming from database in `$data` but not able to encode it.
`$data` containing following data

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [doctor_id] => 1
            [d_name] => Rahul Kenewadekar
            [country] => India
            [year] => DNB - 2012 to 2014
            [profile_image] => Rahul_Kenewadekar-1439468566.jpg
            [department] => Fellowship in MAS � DNB (Minimal Access Surgery -
Diplomate of National Board)
        )
```

Comment: That means the data was inserted with a different connection encoding than you're using to now query the db. It's already wrong in the db, or the connection is misconfigured. Probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your database and table's encoding type(charset). Also you can check in app/config/database.php if the setting is set as below:

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG
{
    var $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'XXXXXX',
        'password' => 'XXXXXXXX',
        'database' => 'XXXXXXXX',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
```

You can also try doing "SET NAMES UTF8" before executing any query and just after doing connection to your DB.

Comment: Thanks Keyur it worked for me as i had commented  'encoding' => 'utf8' in my database.php